# Googled "Can a VBA function in Excel return the cell ids of a range?"

Tags: vba, excel

I believe I'm looking for the inverse of the Range Function.  I have a named range in my worksheet and in an event macro. I'm interested in getting the range definition string back, such as "A1:A12".

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim MyData As Range
    Dim r As Long
    With Me.ListBox1
        .RowSource = ""
        Set MyData = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D100")   'Adjust the range accordingly
        .List = MyData.Cells.Value
        For r = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .List(r, 3) = "" Then
                .RemoveItem r
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

I'd rather use the name of the Range in the `"Set MyData ="` statement above instead of hard-coding the range in the event macro.

Comment: could you share your `Named Range` defintion ? what is the name of your `Name Range` ? is it Workbook level or Worksheet level ?

Comment: If you want to set `myData` to the range on the "OnlinePayees" worksheet which has a "name" of "OnlinePayeeNames", you can just use `Set MyData = Worksheets("OnlinePayees").Range("OnlinePayeeNames")`

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the address of a Range, use

```
Dim MyRange as Range
Set MyRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D100")
' Here do what you want
Msgbox MyRange.Address
```

.Address will return the "A2:D100" address

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/ff837625.aspx

Comment: I'm interested in leaving the definition of the range in the worksheet rather than hard-coding it in the event macro.  I tried:

Comment: Could you explain your difference between "range definition" and "hard-coding" ?

Comment: I'm interested in leaving the definition of the range in the worksheet rather than hard-coding it in the event macro.  I tried:

msgbox Worksheets("OnlinePayees").OnlinePayeeNames.Address

where OnlinePayeeNames is the Range name, but got #438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Try `Worksheets("OnlinePayees").Range("OnlinePayeeNames").Address`

Comment: I used "Range definition" to be what I defined in the woorksheet itself using the Name Manager.  "Hard-coded" I meant a macro statement such as  Range("A2:D100")
Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, that is so beautiful... Thank you CLR.  I've been programming for 50 years, but there are new wrinkles all the time.